# send to many files from an applet to an servlet

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, applet

I need to send X number of files to my servlet from an applet, which is the best way to do this?
And I need to send before the files, a java object populated.
I need to do it all in a single connection.

I'll upload my applet 3 ~ 10mb to my servlet.

I currently use FileInput together with the OutputStream and BufferedOutputStream to send a file, causing the buffer size is 8K.

First time I'll try to zip all the files to upload a zip file to the servlet, but I know it's not a good solution.

Comment: *"zip.. but I know it's not a good solution."*  Why not?

Comment: I do think by getting a very large file and to send a single connection to the server. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the Applet side, send it as a normal [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html) request by either [`URLConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) or [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). In the Servlet side, use either [`HttpServletRequest#getParts()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) or [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) to extract the parts from the request. This way the applet and servlet are not tight coupled to each other, but just reuseable on different servers (e.g. PHP) and/or clients (e.g. a simple HTML page).

Whether or not to zip the individual files into a single zip file is a decision you'd need to make yourself based on coding and performance impact.

Comment: I'll try that. Sorry it may take to respond, and can not test now. For now i could send an object and a single zip file.